# What efficiency would you be working on in this problem?

Tags: percentages

So let's say a specific task would take 80 seconds by yourself. But you have 3 other friends working on the task with you. The task now only takes 28.57 seconds. So if when you were working by yourself you were working at 100% efficiency, How much slower are you and your friends while working together?

Comment: What's the question?  How are you defining "efficiency"?

Comment: Well if one person working at 100% efficiency it takes 80 seconds. Meaning that if everyone was working at 100% would take 20 seconds. But the task is taking 8.57 seconds longer. My question is "How much slower are you and your friends while working together?"

Comment: Your "efficiency" would probably be $\color{blue}{\frac{20}{28.57}\approx 70\%}$. You four are expected to take $20$ seconds (if 100% efficient), but took $28.57$ instead. (Using similar formula, if you guys somehow took $10$ seconds instead, your efficiency would be $\frac{20}{10}=200\%$.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [here](https://www.accaglobal.com/us/en/student/exam-support-resources/foundation-level-study-resources/ma1/technical-articles1/standard-hour.html):

> The efficiency ratio measures whether the production output for a period in a production cost centre took more or less direct labour time than expected. It is calculated as: $$\dfrac{\text{Expected direct labour hours of actual output}}{\text{Actual direct labour hours worked}} * 100\%$$

So, in your case,

$$\text{Efficiency ratio} = \dfrac{20}{28.57} * 100\% \simeq 70.004\%$$